# div inner border radius not working when animating with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

My div inner border does not work when i dynamically change border width by java script but it works when  i do not use js.I am animating div increasing and decreasing divs border width.But Inner border radius does not appear when increasing the div size during animation.
Thanks in advance.`

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.animation{
margin:0 auto;
padding:10px;
width:300px;
height:300px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:center;
}
.radius-all { border-radius: 20px; -moz-border-radius: 20px; -webkit-border-radius: 20px; }
.template-bg { background: #FFF; }
.template-border { border: 10px solid rgba(100,100,100, 0.5); }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var i=40;var flag=1;
function animate(){

  setTimeout(function () {    
     document.getElementById('animation').style.border = "#CCC "+i+"px"+ " solid";/*problem here*/ 
     document.getElementById('animation').style.width =(320-i)+'px';
     document.getElementById('animation').style.height = (320-i)+'px';
      if(flag)
      i++;
      else
      i--;
      if (i <40) {
          if(i<0){
          flag=1;
          }
        animate(); 
      }else{
      i=40;
      flag=0;
      animate();
      }           
   }, 40)
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="animate()">
<div class="animation body template-bg template-border radius-all" id="animation">
This is a div
</div>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the animation. The border-widht just gets bigger than outer-radius, hence inner-radius will be zero. If you'd [increase the border-radius](http://jsfiddle.net/rj1ymfk6/) to 40, the inner-radius is shown, and will be zero only when border-widht is 40.

Comment: How can i fixed it? please

Comment: its ok Teemu thanks.it is solved increasing border radius to 40

Comment: what's up with the down votes? please

Comment: I didn't vote down, but ... The question has not a clear problem statement, only you say is "it doesn't work". You should describe what you expect your code to do, and what it does instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jQuery and work very easy

and simple code for this work

```
function animate(){
     var bw;
     if($("#animation").css("border-radius")=="40px"){
          bw=0;
     }else{
          bw=40
     }
     $("#animation").animate({"border-radius":bw,"width":320-bw,"height":320-bw},200,function(){
           animate();
     });
}
```

and use style attribute for animation tag

```
#animation{
    border:20px solid #ccc;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:10px;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:center
}
```

Comment: your suggestion works but i want inner border-radius for div.

Comment: you can replace border-width with border-radius